# Remove wet sand and mud from shoes

Tags: cleaning, shoes

I was running, and i must have zoned out, because the next thing i knew, I had ran into a sand pit. It had just rained the other day,so the sand was really muddy, and now they are covered in dried mud/sand. I tried scrubbing it off with a wet towel, but it just wouldn't come off. Do you guys (and gals) have any suggestions on how to clean the shoes?

[image]

[image]

Image source: http://www.dickssportinggoods.com/product/index.jsp?productId=93354126

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let them dry. Rubbing the wet sand just grinds it into the fabric.

Then bang them repeatedly on your front steps (outdoors, the sand will fly everywhere).  Also bang them upside down to get the sand out from inside.

To be extra thorough you can unlace them.

Source: often run and hike in mud.

Answer (score 3):

Hose with a nozzle.  Flush it out.

[image]

Comment: @kenorb It is an answer.  It is two lines.  And it meet minimum length.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your shoes, but if it's mostly soft fabrics like plenty of sneakers; you can just throw them in the washing machine.

Let dry for couple of days, should be good.